Azure Redis Cache not found in AzureClientFactoryBuilder Isolated .NET 8
I'm working on an Isolated .NET 8 Azure Functions project
I want to use Azure Redis Cache using the IServiceCollection and AzureClientFactoryBuilder in the program.cs file.
I'm able to use ServiceBusClient and EventHubProducerClient by installing the following packages:
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.EventHubs
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus
services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder=>{ clientBuilder.AddEventHubProducerClient(eventHubConnectionString,eventHubName); clientBuilder.AddServiceBusClient(serviceBusConnectionString); }
But I cannot do the same for Azure Redis Cache after installing the following package:
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Redis
I would expect to find a method like:
services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder=>{ clientBuilder.AddRedisCache(redisCacheConnectionString); }
But I can't find any method related to Redis Cache.
Is there something I'm missing?


Yes, indeed the support of Azure Redis cache is not available for AzureClientFactoryBuilder alike EventHub and ServiceBus but alternatively, you can use Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis package to establish a connection to Azure Redis cache in .Net8 isolated azure function.
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Redis package provide support of input, output binding and trigger for Azure isolated function.
I have the following code to retrieve a value using redis cache.

RedisFunction.cs-
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _78546446
{
    public class RedisFunction
    {
        private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public RedisFunction(IDistributedCache cache, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _cache = cache;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RedisFunction>();
        }

        [Function("RedisFunction")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            
            if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
            }

            // Example of setting a value in Redis
            await _cache.SetStringAsync("TestKey", "TestValue");

            var value = await _cache.GetStringAsync("TestKey");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Retrieved value from Redis: {value}");
        }
    }
}

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78546446</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.3-preview2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis" Version="9.0.0-preview.4.24267.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Program.cs -
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = "<redisCacheConnectionString>";
            options.InstanceName = "<AzureRedisCache_instanceName>";
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

I am able to retrieve a value from Redis.
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801 Commit hash: N/A +5ac2f09758b98257e728dd1b5576ce5ea9ef68ff (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669

[2024-05-29T08:42:16.410Z] Found C:\Users\******\78546446\78546446.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-05-29T08:42:19.707Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 26968) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-05-29T08:42:19.756Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        RedisFunction: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-29T08:42:20.056Z] Executing 'Functions.RedisFunction' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-05-29T14:12:20.0254156+05:30', Id=d803ec2c-0db7-4588-b2ae-d09305d69146)
[2024-05-29T08:42:20.060Z] Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2024-05-29T13:28:00.0000000+05:30
[2024-05-29T08:42:20.159Z] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 5/29/2024 2:12:20 PM
[2024-05-29T08:42:20.159Z] Next timer schedule at: 5/29/2024 1:28:00 PM
[2024-05-29T08:42:22.332Z] Retrieved value from Redis: TestValue
[2024-05-29T08:42:22.366Z] Executed 'Functions.RedisFunction' (Succeeded, Id=d803ec2c-0db7-4588-b2ae-d09305d69146, Duration=2331ms)

You can also  configure the cache clients using StackExchange.Redis package.

I tried this approach and it works. Im just curious about why when using _cache.SetStringAsync("key","value") it saves a hash instead of a string, is there something I should know about IDistributedCache and Redis types?

@AlejandroAlvarez refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0 for types of caching
